# Unity - COMPLETELY disabling component

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

When we disable components like this,

`public Behaviour C;`
`C.disabled = true`

For example, If component C makes its public bool variable B to true when collided, It would actually turn it true even if it is disabled. How can I make components completely froze?

Answer (score 0):

Note from [`MonoBehaviour.OnCollisionEnter`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnCollisionEnter.html)

> Collision events will be sent to disabled MonoBehaviours, to allow enabling Behaviours in response to collisions.

(The same also applies to [Trigger](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnTriggerStay.html) events btw.)

If you want to go sure then you have to implement it according to your needs  e.g. by checking [`enabled`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Behaviour-enabled.html) for every method call (Except maybe `OnEnable`, `OnDisable`, `OnDestroy`, etc ^^)

```
private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
{
    if(!enabled) return;

    ...
}
```

Anyway you can still call and access any other `public` method/field/property so disabling a component doesn't automatically mean you block any access to it!